# How to get live preview of SLIDING LAYOUT in android studio?

Tags: android, sliding

I am using AndroidSlidingUpPanel library and wondering how to get a live preview of "SLIDING LAYOUT" content in android studio?

I can't find any easy solution and just create it in a new file and copy and paste code in the main file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android Studio can't show to you **live preview** of view elements. Because it's just simple render known elements from xml layout. You must using [emulator](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html) to look at "live" work of elements. You can create it from menu preference "AVD (Android Virtual Device), or use other emulators, like [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/#!/download). Also, you can run your app on real device, connected to your PC.